# Is $SU(2)$ coherent state normalized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, coherent-states

I know Glauber coherent state are normalized such that the inner product of < α|α > =1 where |α > is Glauber coherent state.
My question is (is SU(2) COHERENT STATE NORMALIZED)?

I MEAN IF |Z> IS SU(2) COHERENT STATE IS < Z|Z > =1 .
I can prove that it is but when I applied this in numerical examples I find it does not satisfy this relation?

SU(2)coherent state ALSO CALLED SPIN COHERENT STATE

Comment: What is the numerical expression you're trying to use? SU(2) is compact, so you should be able to divide your states by some (set of) constants to normalise everything.

Comment: the capitalization is extremely annoying…

Answer (score 1):

No. the usual spin coherent state
$$
|z\rangle \equiv  \exp\{z J_-\}|j,j\rangle, \quad \langle z|\equiv \langle j,j|\exp\{\bar z J_+\}
$$
is not normalized. Instead
$$
\langle z'|z\rangle = (1+\bar z' z)^{2j},
$$
and the overcompleteness relation is
$$
{\mathbb I}= \frac{2j+1}{2\pi i} \int_{{\mathbb C}}\frac{d\bar z\wedge dz}{(1+\bar z)^{2j+2}}|z\rangle\langle z|
$$

The reason for not normalizing it is that depending only holomorphically of $z$ (i.e not on $\bar z$) is useful for various resons such as computing Berry phases.

Comment: I would claim that not normalizing cs is the exception rather than the rule.  Certainly in most applications to quantum optics or atomic physics one does work with the normalized version.